UK short-term student visa refusal, I have an offer from an Irish university for BSc and I don't want to make any mistakes
I am a Syrian student and as you know it is very difficult to have a visa after the war in Syria. I applied last year for a short-term student visa in the UK to study English but it was refused and the reason was that I didn't show evidence that I will go back home, even though I was doing exactly what my solicitor said, being an engineering student and working and showing a letter from my employer to have time off during the course, but that wasn't enough. Anyway, I have an offer now from an Irish university for a BSc as I had an English test and have the desired score for the course, so I am trying my best to make the right steps in order not to have another refusal. What are your recommendations? I don't want to lie but I am so afraid to have another refusal, especially that I am Syrian.
What should I do?

Related issue in this question.

You might also take a look at this question, which addresses the lie/tell the truth issue.
